# Is "as of current" same as "currently"?

Tags: phrases, usage

I saw a writing by a friend of mine who uses `as of current`. I normally see `as of` followed by a specific date, like `as of 2017`. I am curious to know if `as of current` is a proper usage for `as if`.

Comment: What language is this in? "As of current" does not appear to be English.

Comment: Indeed. My guess would be that this is an original, if awkward, way to say _currently_ or _as of now_.

Comment: I would normally say "as of now".

Comment: Unless he is using an archaic writing style to compare something to electricity?

Comment: @tchrist - It looks like Engfish (a language that resembles English, but isn't...)  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As of current" is not grammatically correct, and it is not typically used by native speakers. The phrase "as of..." expects a specific date or time. Also, "current" is an adjective and doesn't make sense in this context.

Alternatives would be:

- `As of [the current date]`
- `As of now`
- `Currently` (note that *currently* is an adverb while *current* is an adjective. You could say "I currently work as a doctor" but **not** "I current work as a doctor").